# Get multiple api calls in for loop in service - NGRX

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have a array of bike objects and want to perform multiple api calls based on the amount of bike objects.
But i don't think using a for loop to call multiple api's are the best way of doing this.

Are there some better preferences to do this ?

**Effects.ts**

```
  public getMyBikes = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(getBikes),
      withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getBikes)),
      switchMap(([_, bikes]) =>
        this.myService.getSelectedBikes(bikes).pipe(
          map(() => {
            return bikesSuccess();
          }),
          catchError((error: Error) => of(bikesError({ error }))),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

**Service.ts**

```
  public getSelectedBikes(
    bikes: Array<Bike>,
  ): Observable<Bike> {
    for (let i = 0; i < bikes.length; i++) {
      this.http.get<Bike>(
        `${this.myUrl}/BikesInfo/${items[i].bikeId}`,
      );
    }
  }
```

I also tried it with a Promise but then i have some issues with the Observable in the effects.

```
  public async getSelectedBikes(
    bikes: Array<Bike>,
  ): Promise<Observable<Bike>> {
    for await (const bike of bikes) {
      this.http.get<Bike>(
        `${this.myUrl}/BikesInfo/${bike.bikeId}`,
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In order for you to receive data from the `httpClient` you have to subscribe to the request, e.g.

```
this.http.get<Bike>(`${this.myUrl}/BikesInfo/${items[i].bikeId}`).subscribe();
```

this subscription happens by itself when an observable is passed in the effects used by NGRX, imagine that there is a `subscribe()` somewhere at the end of the effects, that will subscribe to whatever observable you are passing.

The issue with the second approach is once again related to the way Obervables work, you are not able to `await` the Observable. Probably if you turn those

In order to achieve the desired result you should combine the requests with an operator like `combineLatest`, which will wait for all observables (requests in the current case) to complete and then will return an array with the aggregated response as seen below.

```js
const {of, map, filter, switchMap, combineLatest} = rxjs;


const actionType = 'GET BIKE ACTION';

const effectStreamMock = of({
  type: actionType,
  bikes: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
});

const getBikeHttp = (i) => {
  return of({ name: `Bike No: ${i}` });
};

const effect = effectStreamMock.pipe(
  filter((x) => x.type === actionType), // the same things as ofType
  switchMap((x) => {
    return combineLatest(x.bikes.map((bikeId) => getBikeHttp(bikeId))).pipe(
      map((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        //  Dispatch success here
        return response;
      })
    );
  })
);
// Imageine that the next line happens somewhere in the internals of NGRX
effect.subscribe();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@^7/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```